# Should "Organization" here be preceded by "The?"

Tags: articles, definite-article

To put or not to put "The"...

In my made up examples below, do I keep the "The" or not? Why? Does it even make a difference?

> 1. The results speak to **the** organization the infrastructure lacks.
> 2. The results speak to **the** lack of organization the infrastructure has.

in #2 I would lean towards leaving "The" out because I believe it would sound more native, but not sure why.

Leaving "The" out in #1 would sound a little odd to my ear and as if something's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need the "the" in both. Also, you should use "that" in both.**

> 1. The results speak to the organization the infrastructure lacks.

First off, this needs the "the" before organization. This is referring to a specific thing that the infrastructure lacks and needs the definite article ("the") there.

An important note: this should have a "that" after organization. This makes the sentence structure a lot clearer, according to my instincts in native American English. Without it, it looks a lot like two sentences you forgot to put a period between. Thus, the correct version of the sentence would be:

> The results speak to *the* organization *that* the infrastructure lacks.

On to the second sentence:

> 2. The results speak to the lack of organization the infrastructure has.

This also needs the definite article. It's basically the same sentence with a different verb and "lack of" added, and follows the same reasoning. It also needs a "that", and, if you want this same exact wording (which I don't really recommend), the correct version would be:

> The results speak to *the* lack of organization *that* the infrastructure has.

**What I really recommend that has the exact same meaning would be:**

> The results speak to the infrastructure's lack of organization.

Comment: Would you recommend, "The results speak to the infrastructure's lack of organization?"

Comment: @Bahram That's perfectly valid and clear.

Comment: @Bahram yup, that's about the best you could get with that wording :-)

Comment: How can I improve this (seeing as it has a DV)?